# How to redirect users from old domain to new domain, if they have cached the site

Tags: nginx, redirect, dns, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

My old domain is no longer valid, I have changed the product name.
I want to redirect all old users to my new domain.
I told my domain-provider to 301 send them to my new domain.

My issue is that when I try to redirect them, they get stuck at the old domain, with an empty page.
For new users this is not an issue, but for the old users who have cached the site once, they get stuck at an semi-empty cached page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain-provider is Loopia.

I tried to disable 301 at Loopia, and redirect with Nginx, and brute redirect at my website to the new domain, without success.

I called them, and they could redirect to their PHP Apache server, and from there redirect to my new domain which resolved my issue.